# SSD Mobilenetv2 detection score is higher than 1

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, mobilenet

I trained different models and I am using the same code for the evaluation. The problem is that the detection score for the mobilenetv2 is higher tha 1. Sometimes it goes up to 3-4.

Comment: Can you show what are the values? I have and its always the softmax value 0-1. Give some additional information.

Comment: I used this tutorial for the training: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10 With Mobilenet v1 it is working well, but with the v2 I am getting these results: person: 1.442
person: 2.421
person: 3.071
person: 0.972
person: 3.934
person: 1.471
person: 2.260
person: 3.262
person: 1.153
person: 3.177
person: 2.201
...

Comment: The output of Mobilenet v1: person: 0.921
person: 0.816
person: 0.924
person: 0.982
person: 0.752
person: 0.950
person: 0.923
person: 0.735
person: 0.969
person: 0.748
person: 0.787...